# Check usage of a dimension in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, measure

I have two time dimensions `[date.daily]` and `[date.weekly]`. My calculated member depends on type of the time dimension.

How can I check what time dimension is used in my calculated member?

Is it function like this `[date.daily].Level is null`?

Answer (score 0):

You can check what time dimension is used by opening the query in calculated fields in a tab `Calculations`.

If that's what used in query `[date.daily].Level is null` so the answer is yes, dimension `[date.daily]` is used.